# Extract string and number from a string which is in multiple format using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a string using regex which is in particular format to get details out of it. I can have my string in two formats -

**First format**

One way is to have a  `foldername-version.tgz`. Here `foldername` can be any string in any format. It can have another or multiple `-` in it or anything else.

For example:

- **hello-1234.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `hello` and `Version` as `1234`
- **world-12345.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `world` and `Version` as `12345`
- **hello-21234-12345.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `hello-21234` and `Version` as `12345`
- **hello-21234-a-12345.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `hello-21234-a` and `Version` as `12345`

**Second format**

Other way is to have `foldername-version-environment.tgz`. In this case also `foldername` can be any string in any format. Also  **environment** string can only be `dev`, `stage`, `prod` and nothing else so I need to add check on that as well.

For example:

- **hello-1234-dev.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `hello` and `Version` as `1234`
- **world-12345-stage.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `world` and `Version` as `12345`
- **hello-21234-12345-prod.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `hello-21234` and `Version` as `12345`
- **hello-21234-a-12345-prod.tgz:** This should give me `FolderName` as `hello-21234-a` and `Version` as `12345`

**Problem Statement**

So with the above two format - I need to extract `FolderName` and `Version` from my string. I tried with below regex but it doesn't work on my strings which are in second format but I want my code to work on both the formats.

```
#sample example string which can be in first or second format
exampleString = hello-21234-12345-prod.tgz
build_found = re.search(r'[\d.-]+.tgz', exampleString)
version = build_found.group().replace(".tgz", "")
folderName = exampleString.split(version)[0]
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: is version always an integer?

Comment: yes version is always an inetegr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
inp = "some text hello-21234-a-12345.tgz some more text"
parts = re.findall(r'\b([^\s-]+(?:-[^-]+)*)-(\d+)(?:-[^-]+)*\.\w+\b', inp)
print("FolderName: " + parts[0][0])
print("Version: " + parts[0][1])
```

This prints:

```
FolderName: hello-21234-a
Version: 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regular expression that captures the components you're looking for within the string, then use `.groups()` to extract the captures.  This worked in my testing:

```
re.search(r'^(.+)-(\d+)\D*$', exampleString)
```

example in ipython:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s1 = 'hello-21234-12345-prod.tgz'

In [3]: s2 = 'hello-1234.tgz'

In [4]: re.search(r'^(.+)-(\d+)\D*$', s1).groups()
Out[4]: ('hello-21234', '12345')

In [5]: re.search(r'^(.+)-(\d+)\D*$', s2).groups()
Out[5]: ('hello', '1234')
```

The trick is the capture groups (`(...)`) within the regular expression `r'^(.+)-(\d+)\D*$'`.  There are two groups - it's actually easier to decode it by looking at the second capture group first, then the first.

The second part of the regex - `r'(\d+)\D*$'` matches the final series of `\d` digits.  You know it is the final series of digits, because the `\D*$` part will match and swallow up all non-digit characters up to the end of the string.

The first part of the regex - `r'^(.+)-'` matches everything before the second part.  It captures everything except the `"-"` character, and gives you the FolderName

Note that you'll need something a bit more complex if you have any digit characters in your `environment` or in the file ending (such as if you're using bzip2 compression)

Answer (score 0):

Use groups to specify the different sections of the pattern. You can name them for easier extraction later, too:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?P<FolderName>.+)-(?P<Version>\d+)(?:-(?P<Env>dev|stage|prod))?\.tgz")

m = pattern.match(ex)
print(m.groups())
# ('hello-21234', '12345', 'prod')
print(m.group('FolderName'), m.group('Version'), m.group('Env'))
# ('hello-21234', '12345', 'prod')

ex2 = "hello-21234-1234.tgz" # No environment
m = pattern.match(ex)
print(m.groups())
# ('hello-21234', '12345', None)
print(m.group('FolderName'), m.group('Version'), m.group('Env'))
# ('hello-21234', '12345', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this pattern works

```
import re
exampleString = 'hello-21234-12345-prod.tgz'
build_found = re.search(r'([\w-]+)-(\d+)-(dev|stage|prod)?', exampleString)

folder_name = build_found[1]
version = build_found[2]
environment = build_found[3]

print(folder_name)
print(version)
print(environment)
```

Output

```
hello-21234
12345
prod
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the best approach, but here's one idea.

Start by determining whether you have the first or second case.

```
-(dev|stage|prod)\.tgz$
```

This regex will determine whether or not you have case 1 or 2.

If it's case 1, you can extract the foldername with:

```
.*-
```

And you can extract the version with:

```
-\d+.tgz$
```

If it's case 2, you can extract the combined foldername/versionnumber with:

```
.*-
```

From there, you can extract the foldername with (again):

```
.*-
```

And the version number with:

```
-\d+
```